# Change an integral from Polar to Cartesian Form

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to convert the following integral from Polar to Cartesian form:

$$\displaystyle\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \int_{0}^{\sin\theta}\,r^2\,dr\, d\theta$$

I think the integral should be:  $\int \int \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \, dx\, dy$

I know the region is in the second quadrant but I'm not sure how to determine the integral limits.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$r= \sin(\theta) \implies x^2+y^2 = y \implies x^2 + (y-1/2)^2 = 1/4$$ $\theta$ from $\pi/2$ to $\pi$ is the left half of the circle centered at $(0,1/2)$ with radius $1/2$. I trust you can figure out the limits for $x$ and $y$ from here.

Comment: Nice that you got over it. Welcome back.

Comment: @Please I figured out the region was a semicircle in the 2nd quadrant centered at (0, 0.5) after I posted the question. However, if $\theta$ only goes from $\frac{pi}{2}$ to $\pi$ shouldn't it be a quarter circle? BTW, why do you want to delete your account?

Comment: @EggHead $\theta = \pi/2$ gives $x=0, y=1$ and $\theta = \pi$ gives $x=0, y=0$. Note that ranging $\theta$ from $0$ to $\pi$ gives you the entire circle.

Comment: @Please you're right. I forgot that with polar coordinates, r is measured from the origin not from the center of the circle. Thx!